# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 error

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I am doing image classification but i got  the error for calculate the accuracy ,please help me how to do it.
this is my model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I want classifly the image like this :
label_dict={'0':'buildings', 
this is my classification labels :

```
'1':'forest',

'2':'glacier',

'3':'mountain',

'4':'sea' ,

'5':'street' }
```

I am using categorical_crossentropy:

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am predicting classes :

```
pred=model.predict_classes(test)
```

I am calculate the test  accuracy , but i got some errors:

```
print('Test loss:', pred[0])
print('Test accuracy:',pred[1])
Test loss: 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b74afa5e2da9> in <module>
      1 print('Test loss:', pred[0])
----> 2 print('Test accuracy:',pred[1])

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If the size of array is n , max index value is n-1 .

So you can access to pred[0] only